# SSIS Package using C# code gives error "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA"

Tags: ssis

I have gone through most of the answers for similar questions here on SO however none has resolved the issue.
We have created a package using C# code which stages data from a source table to destination.

Source Table : RowKey, Col1, Col2

Destination Table : RowKey, Col1, Col2, RowID, RunID (RowID is an identity column in destination table and RunID is a derived column whose value is set using a variable)

This package runs fine when we execute it directly however, we run these packages from a master package. When we are trying to run the package (ChildPackage) from a MasterPackage we get an error:
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: "Oledb Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

We have tried setting DelayValidation to true for the ChildPackage and even tried setting the values for "ValidateExternalMetadata" for the source and destination component as "False" for the data flow task of the ChildPackage.

There is no case difference between column names in source and destination and it runs fine when we run the ChildPackage directly. 
The only task that the Master package performs is to generate and set a variable that is used as RunID value by the child package.

Comment: If you remove the step in the master package that generates and sets the RunID does it still give you the metadata error?

Comment: If we run the child package individually hard coding the RunID, it works fine. Can this be an issue of connections being used? As the Master package uses connection managers defined in the SSIS project whereas the child package is created using .net code and hence uses variables for connections to DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who faces similar issue, in one of the data transformation tasks we had added derived columns and one of the derived column was not present in the destination table. Once we removed this extra derived column everything worked fine.

Comment: YOU are a lifesaver!